# MP4 on Vista not recognised

Tags: windows-vista, video, codec, mp4

I have a video in MP4 format, taken on some type of mini video camera, possibly flip. Quicktime and VLC won't open it because they don't recognise it. Is this a codec issue or is the file corrupt? How can I tell, or how can I make it play?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, MP4 is a container format, and can contain any of several different video or audio codecs.

Both QuickTime and VLC should open MP4 easily.  (Unless you have *very* old versions.)  If you have recent versions and they aren't opening this file, the only possibilities are:

- it's corrupt;
- it's using a rare codec unsupported by QuickTime or VLC;
- it's incorrectly formatted (perhaps *reporting* an unsupported codec even if it's fairly standard)

You could try checking what vid/aud codecs the file reports with [Gspot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/).  You may be able to identify the codec used and google for an installer.  The newest Gspot version can tell you a [`ftyp` designation](http://www.ftyps.com/) (similar to FourCC codes), and the linked website may help you locate a codec.

It's possible the camera uses a proprietary codec that is installed with a driver package that came with the camera, but I don't think this is common.

Answer (score 1):

MP4 is a container format and could contain many different codecs, DivX, Xvid, AAC, H.264 (or the "Mac" format that @Joe referred to).

You need to discover which codec is contained within in order to know how to play this format.

Comment: Technically, DivX and Xvid are just variations of the MPEG-4 video codec.